# Wordpress website stuck on version 4.9.2 it says it is latest update but clearly it is not as wordpress has 6.0+ latest version update

Tags: wordpress

A wordpress website says it is having the latest wordpress update which it is clear that it isn't as wordpress version is 6.0+

[image]

is there a way to make this updatable to the actual latest version, like 6.0+ version.

also the plugins are the same, it says plugins are updated but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when that happens it could be a problem related to your PHP version. If that is too old you might miss some updates because those are not compatibile. Try to update your PHP version and see if the updates shows up